# Why my user controller can't get userid property which i have provided in my USERS Schema?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, api

Issue 1: Why my user controller can't get userid property which i have provided in my USERS Schema? i have given a property userid in my Schema which will be a number, but when i am checking my mongobd to see that is userid is coming or not than that userid property is not even showing in my mongobd..

Issue 2: Why my Schema is replicating 3 times whenever i sign up in my app? the Schema is replicating 3 times but every 3 times the mongobd user_id gets change i think its a bug (Note: here the user_id which i am talking about is a user_id which is created by my controller response and in the above issue which i am talking about is a userid that i want to give to my user which will be much smaller and it will be a property)

Mongobd look like this

```
_id
63613eb2685aa82252cb121b
name
"ecawecawecawce"
phoneNumber
"ewcwaecawecwaecawec"
profileImage
"https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/146-1468479_my-profile-icon-blank-prof…"

selectedCountry
Object
name
"India"
dialCode
"+91"
isoCode
"IN"
flag
"https://cdn.kcak11.com/CountryFlags/countries/in.svg"
__v
0
```

My Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Users = new Schema({
    name: String, 
    phoneNumber: String,
    userid:  Number, // Ealier it was a string 
    profileImage: {
        type: String,
        default: 'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/146-1468479_my-profile-icon-blank-profile-picture-circle-hd.png'
    },
    about: String,
    selectedCountry: {
        type: Object
    }
})
 
module.exports = mongoose.model("users", Users)
```

user.controller.js:

```
const user_module = require('./user.modules');


class user_controller extends user_module {

    static create_user = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.save_user_details(req)
            let message = 'Success';
            res.send({
                sucess: true,
                message: message,
                data: response
            })
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status.code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = err.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message: message
            })
        }
    }

    static get_users = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.retrieve_user(req)
            let message = 'Success';
            res.send({
                sucess: true,
                message: message,
                data: response
            })
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status.code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = err.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message: message
            })
        }
    }

    static otp_verify = async (req, res) =>{
        try {
            console.log("controller response",req.body)
            let response = await this.verify_user(req)
            if(response.status){
                res.send({
                    success: true,
                    message: response.message,
                    data: response.user
                })
            }else{
                res.status(400).send({
                    success: false,
                    error: false,
                    message: response.message
                })
            }
          
        } catch (error) {
            let status_code = error.status_code != undefined ? error.status_code: 500;
            let type = error.type != undefined ? err.type: 'Bad Request';
            let message = error.custom_msg != undefined ? error.custom_msg: "Something went wrong"
            res.status(status_code).send({
                sucess: false,
                error:type,
                message:message
            })
            res.end();
        }

    }

    
}

module.exports = user_controller
```

user.modules.js:

```
const models = require('../models');

class user_module {

    static save_user_details = async (req) => {
        try {
            console.log("req body", req.body)
            const { profileImage } = req.body
            let set_data = req.body
            if (!!profileImage) {
                set_data.profileImage = profileImage
            }
            return await models.users.create(set_data)

        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    static retrieve_user = async (req) => {
        try {
            let {limit, pagination} = req.query

            let query = {}
            let projection ={__v: 0}
            let options = {
                lean: true,
                sort: {_id: -1},
                skip: !Number(pagination) ? 0: Number(pagination) * !Number(limit) ? 10: Number(limit),
                limit: !Number(limit) ? 10: Number(limit)
            }
            let users = await models.users.find(query, projection, options)
            let count = await models.users.count(query)
            return {users, count}
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    static verify_user = async (req) => {
        try {
            console.log("req body", req.body)
            const { otp, user_id } = req.body
            if(otp == '123456'){
                let user = await models.users.findById(user_id)
                return {user: user, status: true, message: 'success'}
            }else{
                return {user: null, status: false, message: 'Otp Invalid'}
            }

        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

}

module.exports = user_module
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the Id because you are trying to get it by user_id, however, It's userid in your model.
Either you have to go with userid OR you have to go with User._id to get your _id which MongoDB creates for every new entry